# Disable HTTP Options method in ASP.Net Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, http-headers, http-verbs

We have a requirement of disabling the HTTP OPTIONS method in an ASPNET Core Web application due as a part of security fixes. How can we disable the HTTP OPTIONS method in ASP.Net core 3.1 API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a demo with middleware:
Add this to your startup Configure:

```
 app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                // Do work that doesn't write to the Response.
                if (context.Request.Method=="OPTIONS")
                {
                    context.Response.StatusCode = 405;
                    return; 
                }

                await next.Invoke();
                // Do logging or other work that doesn't write to the Response.
            });
```

result:
[image]

Or you can apply
[HttpGet]
[HttpPost]
[HttpPut]
...
on your action method in controller.Here is [an official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#http-verb-templates) about the Http Verbs.